# How to get value from input type radio and insert it into database using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to Web Development, so i have this problem. I'm trying to make star rating system with inputs like this:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```

I found this code for stars, so now i want to insert this into database when a user selects number of stars he wants. I want it to be without submit button, so i guess i have to use Javascript and Ajax. How do i take values from this inputs (the numbers from 1 to 5) and store them in database? So when he clicks, for example star 4, it takes its value and inserts it into database. If you have some good links that can help me with this, i would apreciate it very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: don't use values within the html and blindy insert it into a tables.. higher values or subtracting values could be posted to the php script if you do it like this.

Comment: Asking for links to 3rd-party resources (tutorials, libraries, etc) is off-topic.  Also, what you are asking is too broad, as it doesn't focus on a specific problem that you are having with specific code that you have written.  We can help you when you are at that stage, but not at the "I really have no idea where to start" stage.

Comment: I have done it, unixmiah helped me with his answer. The question is stupid, but his answer is what i needed. Thank you all for your responses! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a php, html and jquery which will accomplish what you're trying and maybe this is a good start.

```
<?php
 if ((($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) && strpos(urldecode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]), urldecode($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) > 0) && isset($_POST))) {
    // echo the values from the select facet page
    echo "You have selected " . $_POST['rating']. "<br";

    //do your db actions here
    }
 ?>

<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

<body>
 <form  method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>
   <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=rating]').change(function(){
     $('form').submit();
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I took this from https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1832611 changed a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, its exactly what i needed. I have done it all! :)